# How to use user name and password in AUTH PLAIN?

Tags: c, email, smtp, authentication

I am trying to send Email using telnet and smtp.mail.yahoo.com server. when I try to authenticate myself on server using my yahoo mail ID and password. the server gave me Error;

```
501 malformed auth input (#5.5.4)
```

I am using AUTH PLAIN mechanism. I don't know how to combine user name and password. And after that convert it to base64 and then send.

Can somebody suggest me how to combine user name and password for AUTH PLAIN? Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With AUTH PLAIN, the credentials should be sent according to this grammar (from [RFC 4616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4616.txt)):

```
message   = [authzid] UTF8NUL authcid UTF8NUL passwd
authcid   = 1*SAFE ; MUST accept up to 255 octets
authzid   = 1*SAFE ; MUST accept up to 255 octets
passwd    = 1*SAFE ; MUST accept up to 255 octets
UTF8NUL   = %x00 ; UTF-8 encoded NUL character
[...]
```

It seems common to have an empty `authzid` for SMTP servers, thus this should compute a working AUTH PLAIN message for you:

```
echo -ne "\0username\0password"|base64
```

Comment: my yahoo ID is "sarfraz.streaming@yahoo.com" and password is "password". How I would combine them. I followed your answer but it did not work. Thanks

Comment: How did it not work? What error message did you get from the server? If you decode the base64-encoded string (for example via http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ ), does it make sense?

Comment: I encode it online here [link](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_encode/) using string "\0sarfraz.streaming@yahoo.com\0pasword" with out quotes. And then I give this string to server and it says "501 malformed auth input (#5.5.4)"

Comment: Thanks it was my mistake. When I do it manually using my program it works fine. online encoders were not giving the desire results. Thanks

Comment: Note that echo should not spit out a newline. Thus, the correct command to compute an AUTH PLAIN message is:
echo -en "\0username\0password"|base64